# 当サイトのタイトル

Tags: 討議, 翻訳, タイトル

ポルトガル語サイトのタイトルは「[Stack Overflow em Portugues](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/)」です。翻訳すると「ポルトガル語でのStack Overflow」と言う意味です。

日本語は英語やポルトガル語と違って、独特な文字を使うため、カタカナで「Stack Overflow」を書けば分かると思いましたが、あまりにも「クール」じゃないらしいです。

サイトのタイトルをどうしましょうか？

（念のため、URLは変わらないので、Stack Overflowが何かの形で入っているアイデアでお願いします)

例：

日本語でのStack Overflow
Stack Overflowの日本語版
スタック・オーバーフロー

Comment: 文脈によって最適な表記も変わると思います。どういう箇所で表示されることになるか、列挙・カテゴライズすることはできますか? 今思い付くのだと: ブラウザのタイトルバー、チャットでのサイト一覧、左上のネットワークサイトでの一覧、ロゴ、ヘルプやツアー内

Answer (score 5):

個人的にはカタカナにする必要は無いと思います。
「Amazon.com」は「Amazon.co.jp」ですし、「Google」は「Google」です。
英語版と区別するという意味では下にカタカナが入っている今のベータ版のロゴで良いと思います。

Answer (score 3):

> カタカナで「Stack Overflow」を書けば分かると思いましたが、あまりにも「クール」じゃないらしいです。

"Stack Overflow"を直訳した「スタック・オーバーフロー」だと、正直野暮ったい印象をうけます。このあたりは、個々人の感性によるところが強いですが、少なくとも「クール」とは言い難いと思います。

"Stack Overflow"はそのまま残し、助詞(「の」,「での」など)も省いた「日本語版 Stack Overflow」か「Stack Overflow 日本語版」が良いのではと考えます。

（気にしすぎかもしれませんが、https://japanese.stackexchange.com/ と混同されるリスクを考慮した方がよいかもしれません）

Answer (score 3):

英語版の Stack Overflow に慣れた人達をターゲットにするのであれば、ブラウザのタイトルは「スタック・オーバーフロー」と表示されるよりも「Stack Overflow」の方が良いかと思いました。
そうではなく心機一転、日本人ユーザをターゲットにするのであればこのままで良いと思います。

また日本人は言葉の意味付けを重視します。ですので「Stack Overflow 日本」と「Stack Overflow 日本語版」を別の物と捉えます。
巷の日本のサイトでは、タイトル「stackoverflow beta」の下にサブタイトルの様な物を書いたりします。例えば

```
stackoverflow beta
技術者の為の情報共有サイト
```

といった具合です。

Comment: SO英語版のユーザー分析結果は多くの日本人がSOを参考しますが、あまり投稿やメタの参加はしません。ブランドの力はどこまであるかを知らないため、一般の日本人プログラマーに向いた方がいいと思っています。「Stack Overflow日本語版」などにすると、明確に「ここは日本のサイトじゃない」と思ってしまう恐れがあります。スタック・オーバーフローにすると少なくとも読めるし、プログラミングでも意味があるので、問題ないと想定しますが、私は日本人の開発者じゃないです。mattnさんが日本人プログラマーに向けてQ&Aサイトを作成しようと思ったら、どれにしますか？

Answer (score 2):

カタカナ表記する必要は無いと思います。
ニュースサイトなどの日本語版と異なり対象となる人はプログラマなので、Stack overflow ぐらい読めるんじゃないかなと思います。

例えば、Microsoft が日本に展開するときには固有名詞はカタカナ化していません。
[.NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/vstudio/aa496123.aspx) を見ると、

- .NET Framework
- Microsoft Azure SDK
- Windows Phone
- Visual Studio

などブランド名は全て英語表記のままです。ロゴが英語なのに薄い灰色で「スタック・オーバーフロー」と書いてあるのもロゴデザインとして失敗してると思います。Visual Studio ロゴに「ヴィジュアル・ステゥーディオ」とか書いてある感じと言えばよいでしょうか。

> Stack Overflowの日本語版

「日本語版」と言ってしまっているのはジョエル流に言うと、SE社内の社内構造の leaky abstraction です。Apple とか Amazon が日本に展開するときに、日本人が欲しいのは「Apple」や 「Amazon」 であって、それがたまたま英語版をローカライズしたもとであることは偶然であって、あたかもそれが最初っから日本人向けに日本語として存在していたかのようなサービスを期待します。「Apple 日本人向け」とはもしかしたら会社名とか内部構造ではそうなってるかもしれませんが、外向けには「Apple」と言い続けます。

(If this is too abstract, I can break it down in English too.)

Comment: 正直に、どこまで人が当社のブランドを理解しているかは知らなかったため、少なくとも読めればいいでしょうと思っていました。ユーザーの声100％現状に反対しているし、Eugeneさんのおしゃってるポイントにもメリットあります。もしよろしければ、この回答の提案をまとめて、新しい投稿をしてくれたら、それを注目させ、変えるような準備をします。

Comment: どの点をまとめて欲しいのかちょっと良くわからなかったですが、http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/1433/ を立てました。