# ブランド展開戦略: 「日本語版」と言わない

Tags: 討議

これは[当サイトのタイトル](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/13/)から派生した質問です。

当サイトタイトルのOP (@jmacさん)が例として挙げた

> 日本語でのStack Overflow Stack Overflowの日本語版

で気になったので、ここで改めて討議したいと思います。

「日本語版」と言ってしまっているのはジョエル流に言うと、SE社内の社内構造の leaky abstraction です。Apple とか Amazon が日本に展開するときに、日本人が欲しいのは「Apple」や 「Amazon」 であって、それがたまたま英語版をローカライズしたもとであることは偶然であって、あたかもそれが最初っから日本人向けに日本語として存在していたかのようなサービスを期待します。

[image: Amazon]

「Apple 日本人向け」とはもしかしたら会社名とか内部構造ではそうなってるかもしれませんが、外向けには「Apple」と言い続けます。

[image: Apple logo]

英語版のサイトへの参加率が低いという事が挙げられていましたが、それは日本人の多くが英語を読むのは得意でも英語を書いたり、人と英語で議論するのは苦手という人が多いのを反映してるのではないでしょうか。プログラマの間では「Stackoverflow」である程度のブランド力が既にあるでしょう。また、既に認知されていなくても、カタカナで「スタック・オーバーフロー」ではブランド名として長いし、ダサいです。

[PlayStation4](http://www.jp.playstation.com/ps4/), [X Box One](http://www.xbox.com/ja-JP/xbox-one/meet-xbox-one) など日本では英語表記のブランドが現代的ではないでしょうか。そこで参考になるのが同じくプログラマを相手にブランド展開をしている Microsoft です。Microsoft が日本に展開するときには固有名詞はカタカナ化していません。

[.NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/vstudio/aa496123.aspx) を見ると、

- .NET Framework
- Microsoft Azure SDK
- Windows Phone
- Visual Studio

などブランド名は全て英語表記のままです。ロゴが英語なのに薄い灰色で「スタック・オーバーフロー」と書いてあるのもロゴデザインとして失敗してると思います。Visual Studio ロゴに「ヴィジュアル・ステゥーディオ」とか書いてある感じと言えばよいでしょうか。

[image: Visual Studio]

Comment: 参考情報：[はてなブックマークでの意見](http://b.hatena.ne.jp/entry/ja.stackoverflow.com/)も「スタック・オーバーフロー」という表記には否定的なものが多いようです。一つの参考として。

Answer (score 9):

少数派だと思うのですが、僕はカタカナ表記のスタック・オーバーフローを積極的に使ったほうがいいと思います。
英語版を知っている人間からすると、英語表記が自然に思えますが、**そもそも英語が苦手な人がこの機会に使おうと思うので**、読み間違いもないスタック・オーバーフローとすれば日本語版とか日本とかサフィックスを付ける必要もなくていいと思います。

画像はYelpの例ですが、**お店のオーナーさんなどが英語が読めない**事も多くこういった形になったそうです。
**僕ら自身には英語の方が心地よいのは間違いない**と思いますが、これから利用される方にとっては必ずしもそうではないと思います。
ロゴについてはカタカナにするとさすがに見栄えの問題があるので、英語のロゴに日本語の読みを加えた今の形でもいいとは思います。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 最初の考え方はこれと一番近いです。英語版は知っているなら、問題ないですが、現在当サイトの4000ユーザーの中に、英語版に登録された人が16分の一です。ユーザーの10％ぐらいしかメタに参加しないので、声を出してない人の意見も考える必要はあると思います。

Comment: @jmac メタで声を出してない人の意見としては上のコメントでリンクされた[はてなブックマークでの意見](http://b.hatena.ne.jp/entry/ja.stackoverflow.com/)もデータポイントになると思います。「カタカナの違和感」、「なぜタイトルまで日本語」という意見が何回か挙がっています。プログラミングをする上で `parentNode` とか `AbstractFooFactory` 普通に出てくるので「スタック・オーバーフロー」だともっと覚えやすいかというとそれは疑問です。「ボケて」みたいな感じで「ツッコんで」tsukkon.de とか日本に特化した名前だと面白いかもですが。

Comment: はてなブックマークでコメントをしている人も英語版を知っている、使ったことがある人がかなり含まれる技術リテラシーの高い人が多いと思います。

僕の理解ではこのサイトはもっと幅広いユーザー層を狙っているのではと思います。たとえばYahoo知恵袋にプログラミングの質問をしてしまうような層で、はてなブックマークも英語版も知らない人たちです。

ですがこういう人たちの意見を知るのは難しいですね。

Comment: @YusukeAndo Yahoo!知恵袋は絶対目指していないです。質問の質は安定していないとエキスパートがこのサイトを出てしまうので、目指しているのは英語で読み書きに自信があまりないが、技術のリテラシーが高い人です。僕が6歳に最初のプログラムを書きました（BASICで）。6歳の人はプログラミングに興味あっても、日本語でのリソースがないです。プログラミングマインドを持っている新入社員がいきなりプログラミング部門に移動させたので、初めてプログラミングを学びながら、英語との戦いも必要ですか？質問の質を守りながら、何かの理由で英語を使えない／使いたくない人向けのサイトがあれば幅広い人を支援することができます。

Answer (score 8):

「スタック・オーバーフロー」を選んだ理由は２つありました：

1. カタカナだと、明らかに日本語向けが理解できる
2. カタカナだと、英語が読めなくても読み方がわかる

Stack Overflowだけにすると、英語版と全く同じタイトルになります。

英語のサイトとどう区別しますか？

バッジ、信用度等が英語版と異なるため、別のサイトですが、その区別をしないと混乱するユーザーがいる恐れがあると思います。

そのために「日本語版 Stack Overflow」とか「Stack Overflow 日本」とかがいいと思っていましたが、区別できる提案があったら助かります。

Comment: 僕の提案は日本語をメインで使う（日本人）ユーザの視点から考えると、区別する必要が無いのではないかという提案です。Amazon.co.jp に行くと、Amazon.co.jp とだけ書いてあって、コンテンツは完全に日本語化されています。これを見て本家の Amazon.com と混乱するユーザはいません。日本で Mac を買っても、Windows を買っても、「日本」とか書いてないと思います。逆に言うと、日本は日本語化された輸入品が同名で発売されることに慣れている文化だと言えます。
どうしても差別化したいときの固有名詞が必要ならば、慣例では Gizmodo Japan、Slashdot Japan のように「Japan」と postfix するのが 90s 流、stackoverflow.co.jp のようがより現代的でしょう。その場合もロゴはそのまま。

Comment: top-left の Stack Exchange 切り替えメニューの表記は「Stackoverflow (日本語)」。

Comment: @EugeneYokota サービスと製品の差はあると思います。製品だとサイトがサポートしている物が一緒なんで同じ名前でいいと思います。サービスが違うと少なくともアマゾンと同じように「.co.jp」ぐらいの差がないと同じものだと勘違いする恐れはないでしょうか？

Comment: 僕はカタカナ表記、キャッチーでいいと思いました。ほんとにブレイクするものはカタカナのほうがいいと思いますし、発音間違いも無くていいと思います。
例えばフェイスブック、ツイッター、ウィキなどは新聞などでもカタカナですし。

Comment: Twitter とか逆に僕が推してる「区別しない」派だと思います。言語設定で日本語を選べば UI が日本語になって、検索も日本語のコンテンツだけが表示されて、別ブランドを作ろうと一切していません。新聞がどう書くか知りませんが、Twitter.com は「Twitter」と書いてあります。

Comment: @jmac 誰がどの文脈で「同じものだと勘違いする」ことを心配しているのでしょうか? 「Stackoverflow.com が日本へ上陸。日本語が使えるようになりました。」と「Stackoverflow 日本語版ができました」の違いはあんまりないと考えています。また、Twitter (新聞では「ツイッター」?) が良い例ですが、日本語では英語表記とカタカナを無意識に置き換えるのでカタカナで書いても区別したことにはなりません。

Comment: @EugeneYokota Twitterの場合、サービスは同じです。英語でも、日本語でも、同じAPI、同じアカウント、同じ使い方になります。SOの場合、日本語と英語はアカウント、昨日、データベースも全く別々です。Twitterで日本語か英語かはUIのみですが、SOは言語ごとに異なるサービスです。SO英語とSO日本語はSOとSUと同じように別のサイトですね。

Comment: @EugeneYokota 日本語版を開始してから、ユーザーの声で「英語のサイトを翻訳されただけですか？」とかの思っている人もいました。そして、Twitterで「Stack Overflow」を検索すると、英語版関連も日本語版関連が混ぜています。当サイトがUI的にTwitterと同じように日本語に翻訳されただけと思っている人もいますし、同じアカウントはなぜ使えないとか、なぜ信用度が1に戻ったとかの声もありました。まだ初期なんで、グーグルの検索から入ってくる人が増えると混乱する人が増える見込みです。上記は100％個人の意見ですが、見ている限り皆様がはっきり差がわからないと不適切だと思っています。

Comment: @jmac英語版と日本語版の混同を避けたいという意図に賛同です。ところで、英語版SO内では日本語版SOを何と呼ぶのでしょうか？決まった言い方はありますか？　このBlogを見る限りではいろいろな言い方がありそうです。http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/12/stack-overflow-in-japanese/

Comment: @naota 英語版SOではあまり発表していないです。ユーザーが[meta.se]では「Japanese Stack Overflow」と呼んでいます。社内では「SOjp」「Japlan」まだは「Stack Overflow in Japanese」を呼んでいますが、決まりはないですね。日本語のコミュニティは何が一番適切かを選んだほうがベストだと思いますので、英語の世界で何を呼んでいるかを無視してもいいです。

Comment: @jmacよく分かりました。日本語のコミュニティーから提案したいですね。「英語版SO内で日本語SOをなんと呼ぶか？」と「日本語SO内で英語版SOをなんと呼ぶか？」はいっしょに考えたいですね。特に、ユーザーが他言語版から質問や回答を引用する場合に混同しないように配慮したいです。

Comment: 区別する派が主流みたいですが、「メインの名前は Stackoverflow」という暗黙の縛りがあるため、Stackoverflow Japan みたいなのが普通だと思います。ここで認知的不協和 (cognitive dissonance) が生まれるのは、言語としての「日本語 (ja)」と国としての「日本 (jp)」の違いがあります。ブランドとして受け入れられやすいのは国のほうで、jp の URL を取得して国の方向で行く方が受け入れられやすいと思います。ただ難しいのは米国で "America" と言うと保守派っぽいのと同じで「日本」だと堅苦しい感じがあるので J とか Japan と横文字にするのが多いと思います。国際化の流れとして、より politically correct な ja を使っていくのは悪くはないと思いますが、その場合は "Japanese" と言うと、とたんにかっこ悪くなるので難しいですね。

Answer (score 4):

コメントの方で議論が進んでいるようですが、いくつか画像を貼る関係で回答にしてしまいました。

個人的に「日本語版」はない方がいいかなとは思うのですが、カナの「スタックオーバーフロー」部分については、本家のロゴの同じ個所に文字はない（なにもない）ので気にはならないです。

本家には何もない個所なので、私はあの部分はロゴの一部ではなく補足情報ぐらいにしかみておらず、
その意味で「区別目的でカナが存在するのは構わない。」
というぐらいの感覚です。

無くても許容できますし一方で是非ともあった方がいいとまでは思ってません。

特にロゴがまるまるカタカナになるのは反対です。

---

回答の中で出てきた他サイトですが、参考までにgoogleは「日本」って書いてますね

[image: google]

Microsoftもロゴには何もありませんが、サイトに出てくる文字はカナのマイクロソフトの方が多いです。

[image: Microsoft]

MSの製品の箱にはカナが併記されることあります。

VSは2010までは箱にビジュアルスタジオとの併記があります（下の画像参照。しかし「ウィズ」は致命的にダサいですね（個人の感想です））
2012以降は少なくとも表面にはカナ表記はないみたいです。

Officeは2013でも箱に「ワード」や「エクセル」といったカナも書いてるみたいです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

もちろんAppleなどカナ表記を使わないところも多くあります。  
日本のsonyのXperiaもちょっと探した限りsonyのサイト内ではカナは見かけませんでした。

あくまで「日本」やカナを併記しているサイトもありますよというだけです。

Comment: 参考になります。言語設定によって「Japan」と表示されたり「日本」と表示されたりするようです。プレスや about ページなどで Google というサービスを言及するときに使われている名称は「Google」が多いみたいです。例えば、「[Google の使命は、世界中の情報を整理し、世界中の人々がアクセスできて使えるようにすることです。](https://www.google.co.jp/intl/ja/about/)」なので、Google の場合はロゴhackで国名が入るけど、基本「区別しない」派じゃないでしょうか。

Comment: とても参考になります。画像で比較すると解りやすいですね。カタカナ表記の場合は、文字の長さも大事ですね。長いほど読みにくい気がします。

Comment: @EugeneYokota jmacさんも言っていますが、Googleは実際の内容(検索結果)を含め、サービスを区別していませんね（法律的な問題で実は多少ちがうという可能性ありますが）。しかながらどの言語ネイティブの人が利用しているか（そこまでは言い過ぎかもしれませんが少なくとも現在の表示言語設定）は区別して「日本」とか「Japanese」とか表示しているのだと思います。英語ネイティブの人が日本版を利用するとJapanと出し、日本語ネイティブの人が日本版を利用すると日本とでて、いつもの場所に知らない文字があるとなにか違うと気付けるようなものじゃないかと思います。
stackoverflowは提供サービスすら異なる（英語も日本語も使えるのではなくて、日本語しか使えないサイトサービス）ので、ついていてもいいかなと思います。

Comment: @naota 本当、長さは重要ですね。空白が入っていないともっと読みにくくなりそうです。