# サイト名の決定に進捗は有りますか？

Tags: 機能の要求, 翻訳

このサイトは通常、「日本語版スタック・オーバーフロー」や「SOja」などと呼ばれていますが、現在の正式な（？）表記は「スタック・オーバーフロー」です。これは以前から変更が検討されていました。議論の場は『 [当サイトのタイトル](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/13/3054) 』です。ここで回答を寄せたユーザーの4人全員が、カタカナは良くないとの意見でしたので、これ以上議論が進むことはなく、止まっています。しかし、2014年から「対応予定」のままです。

この件、つまりこのサイトの名前の決定に関し、Stack Overflow社として結論は出ていますか？ まだ検討中ですか？ その場合、ユーザー側の意見がさらに必要ですか？ 現在の状態が知りたいです。

---

#### 追記

コメントと回答、ありがとう御座います。

コメントでご指摘いただきました通り、『 [ブランド展開戦略: 「日本語版」と言わない](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1433/3054) 』においてもサイト名の表記に関わる議論がありました。そこで最多のプラス票を得ていたのは、質問者として投稿なさったEugene Yokotaさんの意見で、カタカナ表記に否定的なものでした。しかし、どうもStack Overflow社側では、ここで意見を取り違えたか、票を読み違えていた模様です。事情が解りましたので、解決とさせていただきます。

Comment: この質問から派生して[ブランド展開戦略: 「日本語版」と言わない](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1433/9820)にて議論が継続したように思いますので、参考情報としてコメントします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

現在、「カタカナを積極的に使ったほうが良い」というコミュニティの意見を尊重し、カタカナ表記が使用されております。ボトムアップなプロセスを踏むコミュニティとしましては、以下のような流れでした。

1. [4名の回答](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/13/%E5%BD%93%E3%82%B5%E3%82%A4%E3%83%88%E3%81%AE%E3%82%BF%E3%82%A4%E3%83%88%E3%83%AB#comment299_1431) をもとに、コミュニティの意見を反映すべく [2014年12月17日 15:20](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/13/revisions) に対応予定のタグが追加されました。
2. その直後、Eugene Yokota さんが新たに質問を投稿くださり、最終的には Yusuke Ando さんの「[カタカナ表記のスタック・オーバーフローを積極的に使ったほうがいいと思います。](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1463/14055)」というご意見に最も多くのプラス票が投じられました。

ヘルプ記事などに使用される $siteName$ という箇所に「スタック・オーバーフロー」が入り、日本語版の正式名称としては「スタック・オーバーフロー」ではありますが、他言語版や英語版と区別するために「スタック・オーバーフロー日本語版」「Stack Overflow 日本語版」とも呼ばれています。

2023年1月現在、名称変更が可能であることを SO社から確認できましたが、2014年の対応予定タグに関しましてはある程度の時間が経過してしまいましたのでタグを外すことといたします。もしもこの先、コミュニティから名称変更の強い要望があり、その投稿にプラス票が明らかに多く投じられた場合には変更をかけることは可能ですので、**新名称の案**と**変更すべき理由**を、どうぞメタに新しくご投稿くださいませ‍♀️。なお、名称変更は安易なものではありませんので、もしも変更すると決定した場合にはその先ずっと使用するつもりでロゴやヘルプ記事など全てに変更をかけてゆくことになります。

Comment: 回答、ありがとう御座います。
事情が解りました。
つまりは、過去にコミュニティー側の投票行動が誤解されていた、という事だと思います。

Comment: 《「カタカナ表記のスタック・オーバーフローを積極的に使ったほうがいいと思います。」というご意見に最も多くのプラス票が投じられました》というのが誤解です。
最多のプラス票を得たのは、Eugene Yokotaさんの質問として投稿された意見で、
《「日本語版」と言わない》
《カタカナで「スタック・オーバーフロー」ではブランド名として長いし、ダサい》
《〔ロゴが英語なのに薄い灰色で「スタック・オーバーフロー」と書いてあるのもロゴデザインとして失敗してる》
といったもので、+19票でした。

Comment: ただ、コミュニティー側のメンバーも入れ替わり、サイトの位置付けに対する理解も変わっていますので、議論はリセットしてよいと思います。
「時間が経過してしまいましたのでタグを外す」ということに賛成です。
私から提案が有りましたら、また投稿いたします。

Comment: 解釈の仕方はそれぞれ違うかもしれませんが、否定意見の得票数を上回る、かっこよくて覚えやすい新名称のご提案を、お待ちいたしております！